# An aggregation puzzle about mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I defined data model like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    content: {type: String, required: true},
    language: {type: String, required: true},
    label: [{type: String, required: false}],
    createTime: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updateTime: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

const Snippet = mongoose.model('Snippet', schema, 'snippet');

export default Snippet;
```

What I want is that when I using:

```
Snippet.aggregate({...})
```

And if the data is:

```
[{
    title: 'a',
    content: 'b',
    language: 'javascript'
},{
    title: 'a',
    content: 'b',
    language: 'javascript',
    label: ['new', 'old']
},
{
    title: 'a',
    content: 'b',
    language: 'javascript',
    label: ['old']
}]
```

Then the result what I wanted is supposed like this:

```
{
   languageCount : [
   {
    language : 'javascript',
    count : 3
   }],
   labelCount : [
   {
    label : 'new',
    count : 1
   },
   {
    label : 'old',
    count : 2
   }]
}
```

I have no idea about how to finish my "..." part.

Anyone who has any ideas about it or any other way can work around it Please tell me, thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your `mongod` version?

Comment: My mongod version is 3.2.1.If u can use some feature based on newest version,I am ok with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following pipeline if your `mongod` version <= 3.2.

```
[
   {
      "$unwind":"$label"
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":{
            "lang":"$language",
            "label":"$label"
         },
         "count_label_per_lang":{
            "$sum":1
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":"$_id.lang",
         "labels":{
            "$push":{
               "label":"$_id.label",
               "count":"$count_label_per_lang"
            }
         },
         "count":{
            "$sum":"$count_label_per_lang"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do when using aggregation is a composed index containing the language:label.

Assuming you are returning a promise, I would do the following:

```
    const projection = {  _id: 1, labels : 1, count:1, languageCount:1 }
    const responsePromise = Snippet.aggregate([
      {
        $unwind:"$label"
      },
      {
        $group:{
           _id: {language: "$language", label : "$label"},
           languageCount:{$sum:1}
        }
      },
      {
        $group:{
           _id:"$_id.language",
           labels:{
              $push:{
                label:"$_id.label",
                count:"$languageCount"
              }
           },
         count:{$sum:"$languageCount"}
        }
     },
     { $project : projection }]);

    return responsePromise;
```

On the caller code you would have to do something like:

```
responsePromise.then((data,error) => {
  response.json({content:data})
});
```

I believe that would do.

Comment: not working ... [ { _id: null, labels: [ [Object], [Object] ], count: 0 } ]

Comment: It was missing a double-quotes in the second id. My answer was edited. Please check it now. I just tested here and it worked.

Comment: [{"_id":null,"labels":[{"label":"old"},{"label":"new"}],"count":0}] by the way,a double-quotes isnt the only part u missed...

Comment: I just copy/pasted from my code and it definitely worked. Please check it again. I would suggest you being more friendly and polite with people trying to help you.

Comment: If my words offended you, I apologized for that...And thanks for your help, I just checked it again, the result is [{"_id":null,"count":2}],  do u think it might be caused by mongoDB version problem, mine is 3.2.1 and my mongoose version is 4.7.4.

Comment: My comments: 1 - Maybe you should use the latest version of mongoose, but I don't believe that's the problem. 2 - There was in fact another typos (which were edited already). 3 - Your label is an array, right, when you save your Snippet, do you set the value as an array? Something like snippet.label = ["new"]? Because if you only put the code like snippet.label = "new". I am not sure if it would work. 4 - Why did you gave a -1 to my answer !?

Comment: About 3, u are right, I am so sloppy, thanks a lot for your answer, I learned a lot from it and about 4, I didnt give u a -1,I definitely didnt do that, now I add a +1 to your answer,  the vote number is 0 now...so it must be someone else...anyway...thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

My final anwser, based on mongoDB 3.4, thanks to @Styvane inspiring.

```
db.getCollection('snippet').aggregate([
    {
        "$facet": {
            "languageCount": [
                {
                    "$sortByCount": "$language"
                },
                {
                    "$addFields": {
                        "language": "$_id"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "_id": 0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "labelCount": [
                {
                    "$unwind": "$label"
                },
                {
                    "$sortByCount": "$label"
                },
                {
                    "$addFields": {
                        "label": "$_id"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "_id": 0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```